# Vehicle Builds For Lego Dimension

Tags: wii-u, lego-dimensions

I just purchased Bart Simpson & a Ninjago character, but when I place the vehicle disc on the center circle, I get a message that pops up telling me that it is an empty disc.

I thought to build the vehicles (the 1st time not upgrades) all you had to do was

> 1) place the disc on the center circle 
>   2) on screen build instructions would appear 
>   3) Save the vehicle to the disc

Why is this not working for these two characters?  If it matters, I am attempting to do this outside of any of the worlds.  Directly outside of the "vortex" that you jump through to begin a level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to build new vehicles, you've got to start with the character.

Basically, the character bases come out of the box to the character, but the vehicle bases are all blank.

When you put the character on the portal, it should prompt you to go to the area where you can build the vehicle(s) for that character.

In the case of level packs, you've actually got to play the game until the point where the vehicle is required, and then you'll be given the prompt to build it.